# after with past perfect tense

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct?

A. I joined this company after six months it was founded.

B. I joined this company six months after it was founded.

C. I joined this company six months after it had been founded.

The company was founded in January 1990. I joined it in July 1990.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence:

> I joined this company after six months it was founded.

Means you joined in January 1990, and the company was formed in July 1990, not what you meant.
Your two other sentences both mean what you meant, the first might be more native.

> I joined this company six months after it was founded.
> I joined this company six months after it had been founded.

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical and not possible to drive a definitive meaning from. It could be parsed and restated as, "*I joined this company. Six months later, it was founded*", but that's not the same thing has *having* that meaning.